# How can I count the number of items in array

Tags: javascript, json

Below is JSON body returned from an API call. I'm using Postman and want to create a test using JavaScript to count the number of objects ("`id`"s) in the JSON returned. Something like `tests["Only 1 login"] = objects=1` is a `PASS`, else `Fail`.

```
[
  {
    "id": 243,
    "user_id": 76,
    "account_id": 1,
    "unique_id": "12345",
    "special_user_id": null,
  },
  {
    "id": 244,
    "user_id": 84,
    "account_id": 1,
    "unique_id": "123456",
    "special_user_id": "staff_123456",
  }
]
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `tests["Only 1 login"]` or how it connects to `PASS` and `FAIL`. Do you mean you want to see if there is one element in the array? Is the array already parsed into a JS object, or are you stuck on how to do that (hint: `JSON.parse`). For getting the number of items in the array (usually known as its "length"), see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

Comment: Please review your answers and accept one.

Answer (score 1):

Or just a count while reading through the array

```
var count = 0;
ids.forEach(x => {if (x.id != undefined) count++});
console.log(count); // 2
```

Comment: This seems to be getting me on the right track. In a Postman test, would I use tests["User has only 1 login."] = count=1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate if you need to *ONLY* count the number of times an `id` property is set upon *EACH* object in the array.

```
var ids = []

for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if(typeof entry.id !== 'undefined') {
        ids.push(entry[i].id);
    }
}

console.log(ids.length)
```

You can also just use `obj.length` if every object in the array is guaranteed to have an `id` property. You said count the number of `ids`, that's why the above for loop was implemented, just to be safe.

Comment: Just `INPUT_ARRAY.length` ?

Comment: @Rayon I guess if it's guaranteed they will all have the id property

Comment: In your answer, if it does not have, `undefined` will be pushed hence makes no sense...

Comment: What is `entries`? Assuming you meant to say `ids`, how is what you are logging different from `obj.length`? if you want to create an array of ids for whatever reason, why not `obj.map(e => e.id)`?

Comment: entries is the name of his object that he didn't give a name for

Comment: @Rayon you're assuming he didn't say get the count of each occurence of an id. He said "count the number of objects ("id"s)", so I was being precise by assuming it's possible that not all objects have an id property.

Comment: @self – Even in that case, your solution will fail.. `ids.push(entry[i].id);` will always add `value` to `array` even if `id` is not the key of the object...

Comment: @Rayon yeah ok, well you should provide your own answer, I don't want to debate you, I'll edit it to check for the undefined value

Comment: @self – I do not find a need to provide my own answer.. It is my duty to highlight errors in ones code so that other will no blindly refer those answer... __torazaburo__ sir has provided most suitable answer by the way....

Comment: @Rayon that's great. Except the OP asked to find how many times `id` is a property in his array of objects -- this isn't that hard to parse

Comment: @self – Yes.. And that is the reason your earlier answer was invalid unser that context....

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is still a string and you need to parse it:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

If you just want to know the number of elements in the array:

```
data.length
```

If some elements might be missing ids, and you don't want to count them:

```
data.filter(elt => 'id' in elt).length
```

Comment: What id `id` is `0`.. or say `falsey` ?

Comment: `in` doesn't care for the value of `id`. It cares that `id` is a property upon `elt`